# eXist-db: xpath does not return a value when xml is obtained with doc function

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

Basically, this returns empty labels:

```
let $report := fn:doc('/db/junitReports/Report.xml')
return <label>{$report//testResult/text()}</label>
```

Report.xml:

```
<junit>
    <interfaceName>InterfaceName</interfaceName>
    <reportDate>2016-06-01</reportDate>
    <testResult>failure</testResult>
</junit>
```

However, it shows entire xml when xPath to a particular element is not used:

```
let $report := fn:doc('/db/junitReports/Report.xml')
return <label>{$report}</label>
```

Which means that the file is accessible from the db.

I found a post where it was fixed by updating exist db to later version, but I am on the latest 2.1.2

Comment: Almost certainly a namespace issue.  I don't believe you have reproduced Report.xml correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I added a "*" namespace to the xPath to solve the issue:

```
return <label>{fn:doc(fn:concat($collection, '/', $child))//*:testResult/text()}</label>
```

Comment: That shouldn't be needed if the XML is what you showed us.

Comment: XML looks exactly as I showed it. It is stored in eXist database.